# How to function chain instead of if else on a variable?

Tags: kotlin, scopes, elvis-operator

Hi I'm wondering if there is a nicer way to write this line of code using scoped functions instead of if else. I want to chain the `.addTOBackStack()` function depending on my `addToStack` variable

```
if(addToStack){
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, feedViewFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
}else{
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, feedViewFragment)
            .commit()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain this, using the [`let()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) scope function:

```
supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, feedViewFragment)
    .let{ if (addToStack) it.addToBackStack(null) else it }
    .commit()
```

It's a little bit fiddly (due to the need to return `it` when not doing any other processing), but it fits within any chain.

If `addToBackStack()` simply returns the object it's called on (i.e. it's a [‘fluent’](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) interface), then it could be a little simpler with [`also()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html):

```
supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, feedViewFragment)
    .also{ if (addToStack) it.addToBackStack(null) }
    .commit()
```

Of course, if processing gets big and complicated, this risks making the code very hard to read — so it's also worth considering splitting up the chain with temporary variables instead (as per another answer).

Answer (score 0):

You cant really escape your if else loop here, unless your `addToBackStack` has some sort of checking mechanism (which effectively move your `if else loop` logic into your `addToBackStack` code)

If you want shorter, readable codes, here is one way:

```
sfm = supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, feedViewFragment)
sfm = addToStack ? sfm.addToBackStack(null) : sfm
sfm.commit()
```

or use ternary to its max:

```
sfm = supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, feedViewFragment)

addToStack ? sfm.addToBackStack(null).commit() : sfm.commit()
```

Comment: kotlin does not have a ternary operator.